# Has Arngeir completely run out of Words of Power?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Arngeir, the monk at High Hrothgar, used to give me word locations, where I would go and learn the shouts.

I have only learnt about 16 shouts right now, and most of them only partially. But when I ask Arngeir, he says: "There is only silence right now."

Has he completely run out of words? Or will he able to tell me more words if I come back after a time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He will have more locations after a short while. There are only a few word walls you will not be directed to by him, the ones that are encountered inside locations that are unlocked by major quests.

If you don't want to wait, shouting in cities will get you a "Letter from a Friend" delivered by a courier with the location of a new Wall of Power.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Why doesn't Arngeir give me locations for Words of Power anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261136/why-doesnt-arngeir-give-me-locations-for-words-of-power-anymore)

There are locations he won't send you too.

So it is possible that he simply run out of word and unlike the accepted answer will NOT have any more locations.