# Why doesn't Arngeir give me locations for Words of Power anymore?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've used a console command to clear the Paarthurnax quest out of my journal, without actually killing him, but now, when I go see Arngeir at High Hrothgar, the "Have you located any words of power" option isn't available anymore.

It's as if I had killed Paarthurnax, but he isn't mad at me. All the other conversation options are still there, everything else is still the same. I care little about the blades, I just wanna get more shouts. I've already cleared every major story arc in the game, including Alduin, obviously.

Can anyone out there shed some light on this issue?

Comment: If you're comfortable with console commands and such, why not just look up the word of power locations yourself, rather than relying on Arngeir?

Comment: Well, first of all, i'm not actually all that comfortable with console commands. On the other hand, quests I can't complete annoy the living hell out of me, so I chose to clear it out, even though I'm not 100% onboard with this method. But now that I haven't actually played the game in a while and I just wanna get the shouts I'm looking for, I might just take your advise. I'd still appreciate some other solutions.

Comment: Related: [Has Arngeir completely run out of Words of Power?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50966/4797)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are quite a few dungeons that Arngeir won't send you to, usually because they are inaccessible until opened with a quest line.  I'll provide both lists in spoilers, and they can also be found [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Find_the_Word_of_Power).

He will send you to:

> Ancient's Ascent (Animal Allegiance)
>     Angarvunde (Animal Allegiance)
>     Arcwind PointDG (Drain Vitality)
>     Autumnwatch Tower (Marked for Death)
>     Bonestrewn Crest (Frost Breath)
>     Dead Crone Rock (Dismay)
>     Dead Men's Respite (Whirlwind Sprint)
>     Dragontooth Crater (Elemental Fury)
>     Dustman's Cairn (Fire Breath)
>     Eldersblood Peak (Disarm)
>     Folgunthur (Frost Breath)
>     Forelhost (Storm Call)
>     Lost Tongue Overlook (Dismay)
>     Forsaken Cave (Marked for Death)
>     Hag's End (Slow Time)
>     High Gate Ruins (Storm Call)
>     Ironbind Barrow (Become Ethereal)
>     Kilkreath Ruins (Elemental Fury)
>     Lost Valley Redoubt (Become Ethereal)
>     Mount Anthor (Ice Form)
>     Northwind Summit (Aura Whisper)
>     Ragnvald (Kyne's Peace)
>     Rannveig's Fast (Kyne's Peace)
>     Shearpoint (Throw Voice)
>     Shriekwind Bastion (Elemental Fury)
>     Shroud Hearth Barrow (Kyne's Peace)
>     Silverdrift Lair (Disarm)
>     Skyborn Altar (Frost Breath)
>     Sunderstone Gorge (Fire Breath)
>     Valthume (Aura Whisper)
>     Volskygge (Whirlwind Sprint)
>     Volunruud (Aura Whisper)

He will not send you to:

> Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary (Marked for Death)
>     Dimhollow Crypt (Drain Vitality)
>     Forgotten Vale (Drain Vitality)
>     Frostmere Crypt (Ice Form)
>     Korvanjund (Slow Time)
>     Labyrinthian (Slow Time)
>     Lost Tongue Overlook (Dismay)
>     Saarthal (Ice Form)
>     Skuldafn (Storm Call)
>     Snow Veil Sanctum (Disarm)
>     Ysgramor's Tomb (Animal Allegiance)

Comment: Well, okay, first of all, thank you very much for answering, but this doesn't actually solve my problem. I'd like to know what went wrong, or how to make things go back to normal, at least for this particular feature, which I always found extremely useful. I'm sorry for being this nitpicky, but it's just that I have no idea of which dungeons I've already been to and which ones I haven't, or furthermore, if I actually found the Words of Power of each dungeon I've been too (each one that actually had a Wall, most obviously). But then again, very thankful for your answer, and sorry about this.

Comment: I think he is saying that you may have already explored all the locations he can give you. You can check that in game.

Comment: @pedro.afonso SMeznaric is correct, I'm guessing you hit the limit.  The list I posted includes the word you get from each location, so you can cross reference if you want.  You could also try shouting in a city like the answer galacticninja linked suggested to see if that gets you a new word wall.

Comment: I've seen this question asked and answered several times, but all of them either regarded Paarthurnax dead or Arngeir actually saying something about Words of Power. In my case, there isn't even an option about the shouts so he can say his "silence" line.